# Find a representative samples from an estimated distribution by KDE

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, sampling, concept-drift

I served a Neural Network model trained on a huge (timeseries) dataset. In production, I would like to monitor the newly received data and check if there is a drift in the features using K-S testing. To run the test, I am required to provide a reference data of the training dataset.

Using the complete dataset isn't an option as the data is highly dimensional and has millions of rows. So I need to find the best representative samples of the training set. The features are continuous and don't follow a specific distribution. For example, if a feature is normally distributed, I would use the Mean and Standard deviation to build the distribution and use it as a reference data for the drift algorithm instead of loading the complete feature.

Some solutions I found are:

- The authors of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11953) suggest to use Dimensionality Reduction techniques to lower the dimensionality of the reference data to a fixed representation by using Untrained or Trained Autoencoder. Then, run the K-S test on the latent code.
- Brute force: Use [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to sample from the training data. Then, keep sampling until the Jensen-Shannon Divergence distance between the sampling distribution and training distribution is within a threshold.

Are there better approaches to find a representative samples for an estimated distribution?

Please bear with me as I am a fellow software engineer who has fair knowledge in statistics.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the testing procedure. Do you a) want to test if new points are likely to have come from the same distribution as the old points, or b) want to test if addition of new points will significantly change the estimated parameters of your model? Also, I don't think KS is the right tool. It is extremely sensitive to even slightest drifts, which are always present in real time series. The test outcome is likely to not be informative, as you will almost always reject the null hypothesis. Bayesian methods may be the way to go

Comment: And one more question. Are you interested in testing individual datapoints (rows), or sequences? In time series it is frequent that any one value is not surprising, but the sequence, such as a jump, is. This may make the problem significantly more complicated

Comment: Where is the estimated distribution? All I see is that you are looking for a nice sample from a dataset.